# How can God be glorified in a man?

Tags: john, jesus

John 13:31 New International Version

> When he was gone, Jesus said, “Now the Son of Man is glorified and God is glorified in him.

What precisely does it mean for God to be glorified in a human being?

Comment: Good Q, + 1, and I just recently answered this question in a recent "chat" room discussion with another BH member, so here, below, is what I had to say and give quote, for all other members to see.

Answer (score 3):

One approach to the question which I recommend is to find out what the glory of God is. Only once we are clear on that can we know what to 'look for' as evidence of God being glorified. Notice that Christ said in the text that he was now glorified, and that God is glorified in him. This means that Jesus being glorified is linked to God being glorified, "in him".

Here is a definition given in a study book on the prophecy of Hosea:

> **'Glory' is the radiance of God's character.** It might be visible - as it was inside the holy of holies. It might be partially visible,
> being represented by angels, as it was to Moses. It might be known
> only by faith. The 'glory' of God in Israel and in the life of the
> Christian **is also the radiance of God's holy character in the life
> of the nation or in the life of the Christian**. He is being changed
> 'from one level of glory to another' in this world (2 Corinthians
> 3:18)... In more than one sense **'the glory departs' when God's
> people sin.** In Hosea's day, the nation's distinctiveness would soon
> be lost, and a century later in Judah the glory would depart from the
> temple in Jerusalem (Ezekiel 8-11). *Hosea,* Michael Eaton, p.145
> Christian Focus, 1996 (Bold emphases mine.)

It now becomes easy to see how God was glorified in the sinless man, Jesus Christ. He perfectly represented his Father while on Earth, doing his Father's will. It therefore follows that all who are "in Christ" by faith, following Christ, should be able to show something of the glory of God by their living. All who know something of the holy character of God and who love him and his Son, seek to radiate their glory for others to be attracted to God and Christ.

On the other hand, those who sin against God are not glorifying God. Quite the opposite - they misrepresent, if not outrightly malign God. This detracts from the glory of God as others see the sin of the person, who may claim to be a Christian, but whose life is unholy due to sin.

This is absolutely not recommending a "holier than thou" impression. God detests such self-glorification, as is shown in Isaiah 65:3-5:  "A people that provoketh me to anger continually to my face... which say, 'Stand by thyself, come not near to me; for I am holier than thou.' These are a smoke in my nose."

No; glory comes to God by those who fear him giving him due reverence in humility and obedience, as did Christ on Earth (Hebrews 5:7-8). **That is how God is glorified in humans. Others see something of the holy character of God** in those who belong to him by faith.

In conclusion, consider this text speaking about the revealing of Christ from heaven with his mighty angels: when ***he shall come to be glorified in his saints [his holy people]*** and to be admired in all them that believe (because our testimony among you was believed in that day). - 2 Thessalonians 1:4-10

Answer (score 2):

**How can God be glorified in a man?**

By force of circumstance, the necessarily *invisible* God needed mankind to be in awe of Him, and of all that He had *caused* to be created. To this end, the Word of God, **Son of God** (His "master workman" - see **Proverbs 8:30**) became embodied in the flesh, in the guise of Jesus. Who better than God's "only begotten" Son to proclaim him.

> "The ultimate purpose of creating and guiding and sustaining this world, is the praise of the glory of the grace of God in the crucifixion of His Son for sinners. This means that the ultimate reason for all things, is the communication of the glory of God's grace, for the happy praise of a redeemed multitude, from every people; and tongue; and tribe; and nation.
>
> All things are created; and guided; and sustained for the glory of God. And that glory reaches it's final goal, in the praise of the glory of God's **grace**, which shines most brightly in the glory of **Christ**, and comes to focus most clearly in the glory of the **cross**" -  From an exposition of "The Glory of God", by one John Piper.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is part of John's basic Christological outlook: the Son is the Word, and the Word is God. So when the Son of Man is glorified through his impending crucifixion and resurrection, God is automatically glorified. John speaks of Jesus' "glory" many times, beginning with the prolog to his gospel:

John 1:14

> And the Word became flesh
> and made his dwelling among us,
> and we saw his glory,
> the glory as of the Father’s only Son,
> full of grace and truth.

For this author, the Son glorified the Father through his incarnation and life on earth, but the ultimate manifestation of this glory was his being "lifted up" through his crucifixion and resurrection.

John 12:32

> When I am lifted up from the earth, I will draw everyone to myself.

The scene in John 13 takes place very close to the crucifixion - just after Judas has left the Last Supper to betray Jesus. In John's gospel this is the crowning moment for Jesus, who even instructs Judas: “What you are going to do, do quickly.” (13:26) Continuing a lengthy discourse with his remaining disciples, Jesus returns to the theme of mutual glorification in chapter 17:

> Father, the hour has come. Give glory to your son, so that your son
> may glorify you... 4 I glorified you on earth by
> accomplishing the work that you gave me to do. 5 Now glorify me,
> Father, with you, with the glory that I had with you before the world
> began.

**Conclusion**: The precise meaning of the verse in the OP is that the Son's incarnation resulted in a process of mutual glorification with the Father. The culmination of this process was the impending crucifixion and resurrection ('lifting up') of Jesus.

Answer (score 1):

The Greek word for *glory* (δόξα) has the idea of *bright* like a bright light:

> And since I could not see because of the brightness [τῆς δόξης] of that light, I was led by the hand by those who were with me, and came into Damascus.
> (Acts 22:11, ESV)

> δόξα, ης, ἡ ... ① the condition of being bright or shining, *brightness, splendor, radiance* (a distinctive aspect of Hb. כָּבוֹד).... ② a state of being magnificent, *greatness, splendor*,... ③ honor as enhancement or recognition of status or performance, *fame, recognition, renown, honor, prestige* ... ④ a transcendent being deserving of honor, *majestic being* ...
> --
> Arndt, W., Danker, F. W., Bauer, W., & Gingrich, F. W. (2000). In *A Greek-English lexicon of the New Testament and other early Christian literature* (3rd ed., p. 257-258). University of Chicago Press.

The distinctness of Hebrew word for glory (כָּבוֹד) has the idea of *heavy or weighty*.

> כָּבוֹד
> ... A. non-theological. —1. heaviness, burden ... —2. a) riches ... —3. glory, splendour; ... —3. glory, splendour; ... —4. distinction, honour ...   B. theological (...).
> —1. to give glory to Yahweh ... —2. כְּבוֹד יהוה Yahweh’s glory (kabod); ...
> --
> Koehler, L., Baumgartner, W., Richardson, M. E. J., & Stamm, J. J. (1994–2000). In *The Hebrew and Aramaic lexicon of the Old Testament* (electronic ed., p. 457). E.J. Brill.

The overlap is glory meaning the position of honorable recognition, and to glorify is to put the person glorified in this position.  What is interesting about Jesus' statement in John 13:31 is for those in the first century crucifixion did put someone in a position of recognition, but it was considered dishonorable rather than honorable.  But, Christ's sacrificial death was a stark contrast.

Paul wrote:

> For the word of the cross is folly to those who are perishing, but to us who are being saved it is the power of God.  For it is written,
> “I will destroy the wisdom of the wise,
> and the discernment of the discerning I will thwart.”
> Where is the one who is wise? Where is the scribe? Where is the debater of this age? Has not God made foolish the wisdom of the world?  For since, in the wisdom of God, the world did not know God through wisdom, it pleased God through the folly of what we preach to save those who believe.  For Jews demand signs and Greeks seek wisdom, but we preach Christ crucified, a stumbling block to Jews and folly to Gentiles, but to those who are called, both Jews and Greeks, Christ the power of God and the wisdom of God. For the foolishness of God is wiser than men, and the weakness of God is stronger than men.
> (1 Cor. 1:18-25, ESV)

> But we impart a secret and hidden wisdom of God, which God decreed before the ages for our glory.  None of the rulers of this age understood this, for if they had, they would not have crucified the Lord of glory.
> (1 Cor. 2:7–8, ESV)

Thus, God is glorified by the "Son of Man" being crucified on the cross.  God is glorified by Christ giving his life as a ransom for us.